# Exception from the jQuery function

Tags: jquery

Variable `a` is always one out of `#u-about`, `#u-projects`, `#u-contact`, `#u-follow`. 
How to make the function not animate `a`?

```
function bla(a) {$('#u-about, #u-projects, #u-contact, #u-follow').animate(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and pass a to not to **exclude** the `element` you do *not* want.

```
function bla(a) {$('#u-about, #u-projects, #u-contact, #u-follow').not(a).animate(...
```

**not()**

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .not() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the
>   matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against each
>   element; the elements that don't match the selector will be included
>   in the result, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: It doesn't work. 
While "a='#u-about'" "function bla(a) {$('#u-about, #u-projects, #u-contact, #u-follow').not(a).animate(" does nothing, but
"function bla(a) {$('#u-projects, #u-contact, #u-follow').animate(" works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/943L3/ 
But I guess it won't work due to inability to upload images.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector to exclude a particular variable or selector from a jQuery object.

```
$('#u-about, #u-projects, #u-contact, #u-follow').not(a).animation
```

Comment: I think that `a` refers to an object, not to the anchor tag.